# Button isn't triggering in python script

Tags: gpio, python, led

Software guy here, first time doing hardware.

Here is my breadboard setup (yellow is GPIO-8, green is ground):

[image]

Here is my Python:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

button = 8

GPIO.setup(button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

try:
    while True:
        output = GPIO.input(button)
        print(output)
        sleep(.2)

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print('cleaned')
```

This yields `1` ... `1` ... etc...

When I press the button, it doesn't change to `0`. But, the LED turns on, which tells me that the circuit is working. Why isn't it triggering the 0 on the script?

Comment: Try this move the button so it straddles the groove in the center of the breadboard, then connect the resistor and LED to diagonally opposite corners of the button. Also, you will have an easier time debugging things if you use red and black for power and ground (instead of orange and green both used for ground in this case). Also, you are using output as a variable name for an input value (that can get confusing quickly). You can even eliminate the orange wire if you use the LED to connect to the ground rail.

Comment: You are using a pull up resistor (internal on the Pin), but the pin is not connected to ground so how is the button ever expected to be low? The way you have it wired you are using the switch like a light switch.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Ok, yeah, something about that seemed weird (again, not a hardware guy), Yes it is wired like a light switch. So should it go like this: 3v power -> Resistor -> Button -> jumper to GPIO pin -> Ground ?

Comment: It depends what are you trying to do?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I want 'something' to happen when the button is pressed. So basically, `GPIO.input(button) == False` (or 0) until the button is pressed, and: `GPIO.input(button) == True` or (1)

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/physical-computing. I linked to the first step but what you are describing is closer to the end. AS a noob I would suggest going through all the steps from the start though.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRobillard. I've looked over that link, and that is, in essence, the same set up I have

Comment: You might find it much easier to use gpiozero, the code will make much more sense. It's used in the gude in the comment above. https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: It looks to me like the ground (green) and power red are both hooked up to the ground strip. Yes, I know that this was several years ago, but I though it should be mentioned. Also, please accept one of the answers so this question won't keep appearing here.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your metaphors.  So to speak.

Either light up the LED (using an output), or use the GPIO as an input.  Which is to say, if you want to detect the switch input, then remove the LED and connect the red wire directly to the switch.  You could also wire the LED in parallel with the switch, but that would simply tell you when you were pressing the switch, which presumably you already know.